# Xcode 7.2 not loading classes in libraries installed through Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I've started a new iOS project in Xcode and have tried installing some common swift packages like SwiftyJSON and Alamofire through cocoapods. The pods install successfully and the full libraries show up under the root project directory, but whenever I attempt to import them into my project Xcode returns a "No such module.." error.

[image]

What I've already done:
 - I've cleaned and rebuilt the project 
 - I've ensured that I'm using the `.xcworkspace` file after installing the cocoapods
 - I've rebooted my mac and xcode
 - I've tried linking the binaries in the "build phases" tab in the project settings
 - I've tried building the project once before installing pods

All to no avail. Here are the versions I'm using:
 - El Capitan 10.11.2
 - Xcode 7.2
 - Cocoapods 0.39.0

Any and all help/suggestions towards what I may be doing wrong are greatly appreciated!

--EDIT (adding podfile)--

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'newApp' do
   pod 'Alamofire'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

Comment: @AnkitGoel podfile added

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following as your podfile. After changing the podfile dont forget to run pod install.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

Comment: Still getting the "No such module" error. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Try creating a new project and set up cocopods again. I have tested and this works.

Comment: I have had a lot of trouble with cocoa pods in the past. My problem is that cocoa pods was install wrong on my mac. Go here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift Uninstall cocoa pods, and then reinstall it via the first part of the tutorial above. You don't have to do the entire tutorial, just part 1 of it. Also, SiwftyJSON is a single file. You don't have to use cocoa pods to use it. Just drag and drop it into your project. I know that's not best practice, but when the library is 1 single file, it isn't as bad.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add Alomofire:** **Project** -> **Target** -> **General** -> **Embedded Libraries** -> + -> **Alamofire**. 
As you see in picture:
[image]